# Heroku error Process exited with status 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I deployed a ruby on rails app on heroku and it crashes. Here is my log file:
I've updated the gems file to include the Ruby version (2.2.4), on rails 4.

```
   11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.962601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.961290+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Awaiting client
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:17.469662+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.127187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:31:46.987348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:35:07.098308+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by [redacted]
2016-05-11T19:35:11.982176+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-05-11T19:35:12.332274+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-11T19:35:17.517913+00:00 heroku[run.8347]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-11T19:59:29.691880+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-11T19:59:34.073559+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 32508 -e production`
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057819+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057841+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:32508
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057882+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057891+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057895+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057903+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057904+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057905+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057906+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057914+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057914+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057915+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057919+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:42.445254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057940+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057940+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:42.445254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057940+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:42.445254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057918+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:42.445254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057918+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057940+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:42.445254+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057918+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057918+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057918+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-11T19:59:41.057941+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-05-11T19:59:42.428116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I think the problem is with some gems but I cant figure out which one. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `bin/rails` file and your `Procfile` (if you're using one)

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'` @Josh that is my bin/rails Im not sure about Procfile

Comment: can you give github link?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a `Procfile` then you should create one.  Here are instructions for Rails 4:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

As a quick fix, you could try changing `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe` to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` in your `bin/rails` file.